# Use of get_prediction method in statsmodels

Tags: python-3.x, regression, statsmodels

I use `get_prediction` method from `statsmodels` to estimate the values of response variable based on new data using `OLS` regression model.

Typically, such calculation is based on estimated coefficients for the same `OLS` equation.

I am wondering if it is possible to adjust the number of significant digits (let say, use only 4 significant digits instead of the raw estimates) to be used in the estimates of coefficients when using the get_prediction method directly.

Any insights will be very helpful

Comment: No, that's not possible, unless you modify the results instance. Why would you want to do  that? Changing the prediction itself would just be `np.round(results.params) @ exog`, but you would need to change also the confidence and prediction intervals.